# Disable syntax highlighting after single quote in HTML mode

Tags: syntax-highlighting, html, delimiters

I manually edit an HTML file which contains plain text and HTML tags. How can I prevent emacs' html-mode to treat single-quotes `'` (i.e. apostrophes) as string separator? For example in `<pre>This isn't right</pre>`, syntax highlighting process the first bit `<pre>This isn` correctly but treats `'t right</pre>` bit as a string. I would like only double quote to delimit strings.

Comment: Does this happen when using `emacs -Q`? Which version of emacs? I tried it with emacs 27.2, `emacs -Q`, typed `<pre>This isn't right</pre>` into an html file, and and it did *not* treat single quotes `'` as a string separator on my machine, so I'm wondering which version you have.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I wasn't expecting my example to be reproducible. The reason why it doesn't highlight properly is probably because of some possibly badly formatted text somewhere before in my huge HTML file. I am just looking for a way to disable to syntax highglighting after a single quote.  I'm using GNU emacs 29.1 on Mac if it helps. Thanks!

Comment: I just noticed that a stray `<` way before the single-quote character triggers the behavior. It may help @djonif too. But thanks for the hint about "garbage" somewhere in front which allowed me to find the culprit.